# Twitter widget height issue, I can't make it the size I need, anybody know a work around?

Tags: twitter

I like many others are not very happy with twitter still for changing their widget support. At the moment I'm trying to fit in the widget they provide to a site I'm working on. I'm trying to set the height to 150px, that's the size it needs to be to fit in the spot where the old one was. I've tried over writing the inline-styles but no luck and I've asked the twitterAPI twitter account with no answer as of yet.

Has anybody found a work around for this?

Comment: Did you use `!important` in your CSS? Please put on JSFiddle.

Comment: I did yes, I'll post a fiddle in a few mins

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mandykiwi/NbF7C/

Answer (score 0):

What widget are you talking about ? A thing from the twitter API like Twitter Cards, Embedded Tweets, Tweet Button, Follow ? Or is it a wordpress widget ?

Comment: [Another site's answer](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/11839) Maybe it could help you, he just add height="150" in the html // in fact you JSFiddle isn't working for me. So I can't really help you

Comment: [Twitter's Doc](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines) In the doc it says the minimum height is 200px. "The minimum width of a timeline is 180px and the maximum is 520px. The minimum height is 200px."

Comment: And with an `overflow:hidden;height:150px;with:280px;` on your <a> or his parent ?

Comment: Both, in the <a> it's set to 150 and to the parent in my css code

Comment: .timeline .stream {
height: 150px!important;
}